# Need help instantiating new object variable from interface import in Ionic w/TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I can't figure out how to make this work. Seems like it should be really straightforward. I have an interfaces file with a CompanyType object (it's long - something like 20 properties). But I can't get it to instantiate in my page/component properly it seems.

Here is a segment from the Interfaces.ts file:

```
export interface CompanyType {  
  address1: string,
  address2: string,
  address3: string,
  ...
  ...
}
```

Here is the Ionic page:

```
...
...
import { CompanyType } from '../../models/Interfaces';

export class CompanyDetailPage {

    company: CompanyType;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        // save nav params to company object
        this.company = this.navParams.get('company');
    }
}
```

The navParams are coming through absolutely fine. If I console the following it works fine:

```
console.log(this.company.address1) // prints correct value
```

But this isn't appearing in the view:

```
{{ company.address1 }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the code in the constructor and not in the ionViewDidLoad() method. you constructor should be:

```
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
                   this.company = this.navParams.get('company');
       }
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Can you explain why by any chance? I though the ionViewDidLoad method is a lifecycle event much in the same as the constructor function. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ionViewDidLoad runs when the page has loaded and you are using company.address1 in the loaded page